# Java socket write getting hung?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, block

One of my exhaustive JUnit is getting blocked in a write in the middle of a repetition.

The flow is pretty much as a passive retrieval on a FTP:

```
JUnit ----------- MOVE_REQ (dst port 4104) --------------------> Server
loop {
    JUnit <------ SEND_REQ with the object (dst port 1104) ---------- Server
    JUnit --------------- SEND_RSP  (same connection) --------------> Server
}
JUnit <-------- MOVE_RSP (same connection as first one) ----------- Server
```

All that chain is executed by the JUnit concurrently in several threads at the same time. The server on the JUnit side (the one attending the SEND_REQ) is a pool of 5 threads, exactly the same as the server on the other side.

In debug I can see the server hung with a SEND_REQ in a OutputStream.write of 16384 bytes.
On the other side, the server of the jUnit is stuck reading the stream with a InputStream.read of just 6 bytes.

The first thing I thought was that I was not closing all the connections and therefore I was having any kind of leak on the buffers. But I have verified it with TcpView and it's fine, **there is only one connection at that time**:

[image]

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Give us some code and work on your rate ;) To your question: I bet it is some kind of deadlock. Threading can be hell sometimes.

Comment: How are you sending data? Which kind of streams are you using?
As Fildor said, pieces of code would help.

Comment: Hi, we are talking about Dicom and a C-MOVE operation.... I'm using proprietary libraries working directly on the input and output streams on a socket (I have the source). The source code I think it's a bit too much to paste it in here. I'm using normal IO sockets... The point and what I care at the end, is that it's getting stuck when no other connections are active, if it were a deadlock between objects it would be hung in a .wait() or similar. not in a .write on a single connection...

Comment: We tested this in several computers with Windows XP, Win7, Linux, and this problem is only happening in my computer (WinXP 64bits)...